# Why does the game I ported to Mac destroy all sound on Mac until reboot?

Tags: macos, core-audio

## The setup

The game in question is using CoreAudio and single AudioGraph to play sounds.

The graph looks like this:

input callbacks -> 3DMixer -> DefaultOutputDevice

3DMixer's BusCount is set to 50 sounds max.

All samples are converted to default output device's stream format before being fed to input callbacks. Unused callbacks aren't set (NULL). Most sounds are 3D, so azimuth, pan, distance and gain are usually set for each mixer input, not left alone. They're checked to make sure only valid values are set. Mixer input's playback rate is also sometimes modified slightly to simulate pitch, but for most sounds it's kept at default setting.

## The problem

Let's say I run the game and start a level populated with many sounds, lot of action.

I'm running HALLab -> IO Cycle Telemetry window to see how much time it takes to process each sound cycle - it doesn't take any more than 4ms out of over 10 available ms in each cycle, and I can't spot a single peak that would make it go over alloted time.

At some point when playing the game, when many sounds are playing at the same time (less than 50, but not less than 20), I hear a poof, and from then on only silence. No Mac sounds can be generated from any application on Mac. The IO Telemetry window shows my audio ticks still running, still taking time, still providing samples to output device.

- This state persists even if there are less, then no sounds playing in my game.
- Even if I quit the game entirely, Mac sounds generated by other applications don't come back.
- Putting Mac to sleep and waking it up doesn't help anything either.
- Only rebooting it fully results in sounds coming back. After it's back, first few sounds have crackling in them.

What can I do to avoid the problem? The game is big, complicated, and I can't modify what's playing - but it doesn't seem to overload the IO thread, so I'm not sure if I should. The problem can't be caused by any specific sound data, because all sound samples are played many times before the problem occurs. I'd think any sound going to physical speakers would be screened to avoid overloading them physically, and the sound doesn't have to be loud at all to cause the bug.

I'm out of ideas.